# How can I clone Bootstrap tabs without affecting existing tabs?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form with `Bootstrap` tabs. There is a strange behavior if I clone all the `tabs` to a new section. If I don't click on any tab and I do the clone then I can select all the tabs on the new created section.

If in the other hand I click by example `Tab 2` and then I clone, `Tab 2` on the new section can't be selected anymore.

**Scenario 1** (Working)

1. Don't select any tab.
2. Click the Add button (in the bottom of the panel)
3. **You wil be able** to click all the tabs in the new created section.

[image]

**Scenario 2** (not working):

1. Select Tab 2 tab.
2. Click the Add button (in the bottom of the panel)
3. **You won't be able** to click Tab 2 in the new created section.

[image]

Here is the fiddle so you can try.
https://jsfiddle.net/dabros/vo1npqdx/

> Any clue on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

Change

```
var cloned = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(true);
```

To

```
var cloned = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

since cloning did not work for me, I am placing just another work-around for that:

```
const copied = $source.prop('outerHTML');
```

or for those, who don't want to use prop

```
const copied = $('<div>').append($source.clone()).html();
```

$ means we are dealing with jQuery objects, which should be present while playing with bootstrap3 pills.

if no there is plain js:

```
const copied = source.outerHTML;
```